# How to execute a command from a NSIS finish page

Tags: checkbox, installation, nsis

After having tried various methods, I never got the finish page with a checkbox in it. Q&A on stackoverflow suggested to use the `!define MUI_PAGE_FINISH_RUN` command just before the `!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH` command.

So I took the example `WelcomeFinish.nsi` and added only 1 line `!define MUI_PAGE_FINISH_RUN "Notepad.exe"` just before the `!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH` command. Still no checkbox on the finish page.

What am i doing wrong? I am using Win7 Professional on a 64-bit machine

Comment: So the example you posted should work, but I get the same result you are describing (the checkbox fails to appear). However, using `MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION` appears to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following NSIS documentation describes how to accomplish this: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Run_an_application_shortcut_after_an_install

You need to add the following defines before `MUI_PAGE_FINISH`:

```
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_TEXT "Launch notepad"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION "StartNotepad"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

We are setting `MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN` to be empty and instead defining a function in `MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION` to be run (we're calling our function `StartNotepad`). It will launch the process we are interested in (or shortcut/lnk) using `ExecShell`:

```
Function StartNotepad
  ExecShell "" "notepad.exe"
FunctionEnd
```